# How do I know whether an instance is stored on GPU with PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

I'm learning PyTorch recently, and this question comes up.
For example, if I have a net inheriting the "torch.nn.Module".

```
class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, something):
        super(net, self).__init__()
        self.p1=something

    def forward():
        pass

net1=Net(123)
net1.cuda()  ##Here I can't see what is changed.
```

Then how can I know whether net1 (and that something) is stored on GPU.

I've read how the *.cuda() works, seems like let all the "children" run the *.cuda(). I tried to see what the "children" are. It seems the net1 above has no children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check a simple tensor, you can check the `is_cuda` attribute. For example:

```
x = torch.zeros(100).cuda()
y = torch.zeros(100)

print(x.is_cuda) # True
print(y.is_cuda) # False
```

To check a model, a think the easiest way is using the `parameters()` method, which returns all trainable parameters of your model.

```
next(model.parameters()).is_cuda
```

Comment: This assumes that all tensors of the model are on the same device, i.e. it just tells you the device of the first. Which may and may not be enough.

Comment: That's a good point. Do you have any hint to handle this? I can't test it right now because I just have 1 GPU available at the moment.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. For reporting/debug, one can just iterate through the parameters. (I do 99 % of stuff on a single GPU as well.)

Comment: Does that mean only trainable parameters can be stored in GPU? I try this just now. I have a class storing several tensors, then I let an instance call the cuda(). It seems the stored tensors are still on CPU. Now I try to register the tensors as its parameters. It works, but seems really stupid. Maybe I should create a method to move them to GPU?

Comment: If your model extends `nn.Module` and you do `model.cuda()`, for example, only the model's parameters are moved to the card. So, if I got your question, the answer is yes. To include more tensors, you need to include them in the parameters, for example:  `new_tensor = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(10))`.